# A problem with jQueryUI draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

[Here is my demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/zhzhzhh/9PUr5/9/), I made some covers on a div, and want to drag that div, but it doesn't work.

-0-,sorry all,I resoved it myself.....[here is the code  lol](http://jsfiddle.net/zhzhzhh/9PUr5/10/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not sure what parts of the page you want to be draggable, but in the HTML you create the draggable div and add all the other divs that are layered on top of it. The other divs are not inside the draggable div so naturally they block the dragging action (there's no surface on the draggable div that wouldn't be covered by a static div).

If you mean all the stuff you have there to move along with the draggable div you have to put them *inside* the draggable div: http://jsfiddle.net/r6PXp/

On the other hand if you want the bottom div be draggable so that you could "slide" it away from the static divs on top of it things get more complex.

Comment: thank's for ur help....but I really want that will works like the other hand like u said....